# How to fix error with deploy my Next.js project?

Tags: web3js, react, error, deploy, viem

I have my project that I want to deploy to Vercel but when I'm trying to deploy it I got error

```
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/@wagmi/core/dist/esm/actions/getProof.js
Attempted import error: 'getProof' is not exported from 'viem/actions' (imported as 'viem_getProof').
Attempted import error: 'withRetry' is not exported from 'viem' (imported as 'withRetry').
Attempted import error: 'withTimeout' is not exported from 'viem' (imported as 'withTimeout').
Attempted import error: 'withRetry' is not exported from 'viem' (imported as 'withRetry').
Attempted import error: 'withTimeout' is not exported from 'viem' (imported as 'withTimeout').
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "@web3modal/ethers": "^3.4.0",
    "@web3modal/wagmi": "^3.4.0",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.16",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "viem": "^1.19.13",
    "wagmi": "^2.5.5",
    "web3": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Maybe decision in Vercel environment but I don't know what to do
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a **compatibility** issue.

You can try upgrading to a newer `Viem` version to see if the build problem resolves on its own.

Ideally, the `viem` and `wagmi` versions should match in order to avoid edge cases and confusions, in any case, `viem` should be at least **>=0.2.0**. (https://github.com/wevm/wagmi/blob/3baed905e25b8136ce9abe6a2a90eddfaee56a84/package.json#L55)